# Autoupdate Title field in Document Library

Tags: document-library

I have a Document Library. When I upload multiple documents into it, the field Title for each one remains empty.
So I can't Check In these documents while Title is empty. But to set value for each uploaded document manually is not the best idea.
I've tried to create workflow which have to set Title value as Name field value, but it had failed.
Workflow can't be started while file is not checked in.

Should I create EventReceiver in this case and will it be the best sulution?

Answer (score 2):

An EventReceiver can be a convenient solution for the issue you have. Check if the title field is empty, if so, set the title to the name of the file. Eventually you can check-in the file if you like from the eventreceiver.